# How to sort panda dataframe based on numbers in column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data file with column names like this (numbers in the name from 1 to 32):

[image: output file read in excel]

| inlet_left_cell-10<stl-unit=m>-imprint) | inlet_left_cell-11<stl-unit=m>-imprint) | inlet_left_cell-12<stl-unit=m>-imprint) | ------- | inlet_left_cell-9<stl-unit=m>-imprint) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | data | data | data |
| data | data | data | data | data |
| .... | .... | ... | ... | .... |

I would like to sort the columns (with data) from left to right in python based on the number in the columns. I need to move a whole column based on the number in the column name.

So xxx-1xxx, xxx-2xx, xxx-3xxx, ...... xxx-32xxx

| inlet_left_cell-1<stl-unit=m>-imprint) | inlet_left_cell-2<stl-unit=m>-imprint) | inlet_left_cell-3<stl-unit=m>-imprint) | ------- | inlet_left_cell-32<stl-unit=m>-imprint) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | data | data | data |
| data | data | data | data | data |
| .... | .... | ... | ... | .... |

Is there any way to do this in python ? Thanks.

Comment: Please copy textual data in the question instead of image to help you better

Comment: @Abhi Yes, I added the textual data above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution

```py
# Some random data
data = np.random.randint(1,10, size=(100,32))

# Setting up column names as given in your problem randomly ordered
columns = [f'inlet_left_cell-{x}<stl-unit=m>-imprint)' for x in range(1,33)]
np.random.shuffle(columns)

# Creating the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df.head()
```

[image: Before sorted columns]

```
# Sorting the columns in required order
col_nums = [int(x.split('-')[1].split('<')[0]) for x in df.columns]
column_map = dict(zip(col_nums, df.columns))
df = df[[column_map[i] for i in range(1,33)]]
df.head()
```

[image: After sorted columns]

Comment: I've tried this also works +1 from my side

Comment: Thank you :) but your solution is unmatachable :)

Answer (score 2):

There many ways to do it...I'm just posting simply way.

1. Simply extract column names & sort them using `natsort`.

Assuming `Dataframe` name as `df`..

```
from natsort import natsorted, ns
dfl=list(df) #used to convert column names to list

dfl=natsorted(dfl, alg=ns.IGNORECASE) # sort based on subtsring numbers

df_sorted= df[dfl] #Re arrange Df

print(df_sorted)
```

Comment: That's new nice one :)

Comment: Yeah...No splitting...No loops..No mapping..,After seeing column names thought to convert to list & sort...Because list sorting is far more easy, simple in python..

Comment: Yeah completely true !! :)

Answer (score 1):

If the column names differ only by this number, try this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("D:\\..\\file_name.xlsx")
data = data.reindex(sorted(data.columns), axis=1)
```

For example:

```
    data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["inlet_left_cell-23<stl-unit=m>-imprint)", "inlet_left_cell-47<stl-unit=m>-imprint)", "inlet_left_cell-10<stl-unit=m>-imprint)", "inlet_left_cell-12<stl-unit=m>-imprint)"])
print(data)
```

> inlet_left_cell-23<stl-unit=m>-imprint)   inlet_left_cell-47<stl-unit=m>-imprint) inlet_left_cell-10<stl-unit=m>-imprint) inlet_left_cell-12<stl-unit=m>-imprint)

After this:

```
data = data.reindex(sorted(data.columns), axis=1)
print(data)
```

> inlet_left_cell-10<stl-unit=m>-imprint)   inlet_left_cell-12<stl-unit=m>-imprint) inlet_left_cell-23<stl-unit=m>-imprint) inlet_left_cell-47<stl-unit=m>-imprint)

​

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but it does not sort the columns. There is no change at all.

Comment: Also works +1 Mato

Comment: If I used your simple code, then yes it works. Does this approach also works with lots of data in each column ? With my data, it does not sort the dataframe.  It is weird.

Comment: Should work. From what type of file: excel, csv, ...? And how many columns are in the file?